# VS2010 Debugger : "The name 'MyVariable' does not exist in the current context"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Is it possible to evaluate a variable that has just been assigned ?

For example, I get that error when I try to evaluate "fiset" below

```
FileInfo[] fiset = di.GetFiles("*.set");
Console.Read();  <--BreakPoint is here
```

In order for the debugger to be able to evaluate it, I need to "do stuff" with fiset after it has been assigned .
 is there a way to avoid this ?

Comment: Can we assume you are in release mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compile with optimizations off (Debug mode). In Release mode unread variables get optimized away.

Comment: Thanks Could you please tell what other impacts this  would have ?

Comment: The general implications of debug vs. release can be found here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaybaz_ms/archive/2004/06/28/168314.aspx I would have to look up what the optimization does exactly. (I mostly answered the question because it happend to me yesterday too.)